# Text not showing in div. Value not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I think I am doing everything right, but something is still wrong.

```
<div class="blok" id="klein_vak">
        Tekst: <input type="text" id="textbox"> <br><br>
        <button class="knop_vak" onclick="myFunction5()">Voeg tekst toe aan div</button> <br><br>
</div>

<div class="blok" id="content_div"></div>
```

Sorry about the class/div names and the text in the buttons, I am Dutch, that's way. 
What I want now is, the text that I fill in in the input field (id of inputfield = "textbox", must be showed in the "content_div".
So what I did in  is:

```
var content = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
        function myFunction5(){
            document.getElementById("content_div").innerHTML = content;
        }
```

But this gives nothing. I tried to delete .value, but then it says if I click the button something like [Object HTML] and not the text that I filled in.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change you code with following

```
function myFunction5(){
    var content = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
    document.getElementById("content_div").innerHTML = content;
}
```

or

```
function myFunction5(){
    document.getElementById("content_div").innerHTML = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
}
```

Comment: Of course, that's it. I had to put the var content in the function.. Could have known.. Thanks for the help!